# MKMapKit practical maximum number of MKPolylines

Tags: iphone, performance, ipad, ios, mkmapview

Is there any published benchmarks or do you have any indication about how many MKPolylines you can add to a map with *reasonable* performance on iPhone and iPad?

I would like to add thousands of them.

What would be my top limit?

Comment: Why don't you try it out and tell us?

Comment: Finally we managed to reduce the number to 200 MKPolylines with a total number of 1800 vertices. It works pretty well in iPhone 4.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about MKPolylines but i have tried rendering 1200 MKPolygons and i successfully rendered it without crashing. But it showed be some slower performance. I dont think there is a limit for it.  What i would suggest is everything is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

My app (Circle 8) has about 70 MKPolylines that all had their own separate MKOverlayView in the map.  Performance/panning was horribly slow and the memory warnings came in fast and furious.  I ended up wrapping all these into a single view (subclass of MKOverlayPathView) that draws each MKPolyline using simple CGPath calls.  Performance/panning/memory problems SOLVED.  To be fair, this was not an original thought on my part but rather came largely from the related Apple Developer Forum thread here:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/328631#328631

Comment: Link is dead  :(